# Header is shifted because title is too long

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-design

*Disclaimer: I'm not a regular user of this site. I visited from Meta Stack Exchange to flag spam.*

The links are pushed out of the header because the title of the site is too long:

[image]

This issue is also present on meta:

[image]

Screenshots taken in Chrome 40 on Windows 8. I was unable to reproduce the issue in other browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next build will fix the issue where the navigation is pushed down for Chrome on Windows.  Thanks for the report!